# python opencv detecting curve points in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

the white dotted circle are the points to be found.
How can i do it using opencv?[hands.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qh2q.png)

Comment: show Code What you tried

Answer (score 1):

FindContours -> ConvexHull -> ConvexityDefects

[image]